# Read JSON-file in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file structured like this:

[
{"ID":"fjhgj","Label":{"objects":[{"featureId":"jhgd","schemaId":"hgkl","title":"Kuh","}],"classifications":[]},"Created By":"xxx_xxx","Project Name":"Tiererkennung"},

{"ID":"jhgh","Label":{"objects":[{"featureId":"jhgd","schemaId":"erzl","title":"Kuh","}],"classifications":[]},"Created By":"xxx_xxx","Project Name":"Tiererkennung"},

...

and I would like to read all IDs and all schemaIds for each entry in the json file. I am codin in python.

What I tried is this:

```
import json
with open('Tierbilder.json') as f:
data=json.load(f)

data1 =data[0]
print(data1.values)

server_dict = {k:v for d in data for k,v in d.items()}
host_list = server_dict
```

Now I have the Problem that in host_list only the last row of my json file is saved. How can I get another row, like the first one?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your code!

Comment: the JSON is far from valid - please amend so contributors can help.  `{k:v for d in data for k,v in d.items()}` dictionary comprehension will just leave you with final dict.  it's synonymous with `data[len(data)-1]`

Answer (score 1):

1. structure your JSON so it's readable and structure is clear
2. simple list comprehension
3. `data` you will have been read from your file

```
data = [{'ID': 'fjhgj', 
         'Label': {'objects': [{'featureId': 'jhgd','schemaId': 'hgkl','title': 'Kuh'}], 'classifications': []},
         'Created By': 'xxx_xxx','Project Name': 'Tiererkennung'},
         {'ID': 'jhgh', 'Label': {'objects': [{'featureId': 'jhgd','schemaId': 'erzl','title': 'Kuh'}], 'classifications': []},
          'Created By': 'xxx_xxx','Project Name': 'Tiererkennung'}]

projschema = [{"ID":proj["ID"], "schemaId":schema["schemaId"]} 
              for proj in data 
              for schema in proj["Label"]["objects"]]
```

**output**

```
[{'ID': 'fjhgj', 'schemaId': 'hgkl'}, {'ID': 'jhgh', 'schemaId': 'erzl'}]
```